# Date function in access vba outputting time

Tags: forms, date, ms-access, vba

I am trying to update a date field in a table to the current date when a button is clicked on a form and that given field is empty. However, when the field is updated, the output is the time 12:00:05, not a date at all. When year(date) is used instead, 7/7/1905 is the output. I am not sure why these values are my outputs. Here is my code:

```
Dim ctl As Control
Set ctl = [Forms]![frm1]![subfrm1].[Form]![CloseDate]

If IsNull(ctl) Then
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tbl1 SET [CloseItem] = ""YES"" WHERE [ID] = " & [Forms]![frm1]![ID].Value & " AND [Item#] = " & [Forms]![frm1]![subfrm1].[Form]![ItemID].Value

DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tbl1 SET [CloseDate] = " & Date & " WHERE [ID] = " & [Forms]![frm1]![ID].Value & " AND [ItemID] = " & [Forms]![frm1]![subfrm1].[Form]![ItemID].Value

' Output is 12:00:05

' OR DoCmd.RunSQL "Update tbl1 SET [CloseDate] = " & Year(Date) & " WHERE [ID] = " & [Forms]![frm1]![ID].Value & " AND [ItemID] = " & [Forms]![frm1]![subfrm1].[Form]![ItemID].Value
DoCmd.RefreshRecord

' Output is 7/7/1905

End If
```

How can I get it to output the correct date?

Answer (score 1):

Examine the string your code builds for this segment of the `UPDATE` statement.  (This is an example copied from the Access Immediate window.  You can go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>)

```vb
? "Update tbl1 SET [CloseDate] = " & Date & " WHERE [ID] = "
Update tbl1 SET [CloseDate] = 2/16/2015 WHERE [ID] =
```

The db engine does not see *2/16/2015* as a Date/Time value.  Instead, it treats that as 2 divided by 16 divided by 2015.  And the resulting number, when expressed as a Date/Time value, gives you this ...

```vb
? Format(2/16/2015, "yyyy-m-d hh:nn:ss")
1899-12-30 00:00:05
```

You can signal the db engine that *2/16/2015* is a Date/Time value by enclosing it in `#` delimiters like this: `#2/16/2015#`

However, since the db engine understands the `Date()` function, you can use that function name directly in your `UPDATE` statement and not bother about concatenating in a value with proper delimiters.

```vb
Dim strUpdate As String
strUpdate = "Update tbl1 SET [CloseDate] = Date() WHERE [ID] = " & _
    [Forms]![frm1]![ID].Value & " AND [ItemID] = " & _
    [Forms]![frm1]![subfrm1].[Form]![ItemID].Value
Debug.Print strUpdate
CurrentDb.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError
```